# Angular event handling, correct practice to use blur and click for same method?

Tags: javascript, angular

this is probably confusing questions to ask, I have a validation method in Angular that checks if I've populated my select or not, basically a small check to the value. Now I saw that if i toggle my form through keyboard via tab key then the (blur) event comes to play and if I use the (click) handler , the mouse click event is checked.

Hence I wanted to check with community if this is a correct practice, if not then what would be the better approach for it , if Im using both the events and calling same methods on them.

Please find the code sample below.

The code below executes both on click and on blur and then it tries to check the value and if value is not there then contractValidationMessage is displayed with some error message and vice versa.

```
<select
                      class="form-control dropdown ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"
                      [(ngModel)]="clientModel.contract.signedBy" #contractSignedBy
                      (blur) = 'validateContractSignature(contractSignedBy)'
                      (click) = 'validateContractSignature(contractSignedBy)'
                      >
                      <option hidden value="" disabled selected>Singed by</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let user of userRoles">{{user}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="validation-msg">{{contractValidationMessage}}</div>
            </div>
```

Just wanted to understand if this is correct way or not

here's the function in case required

```
validateContractSignature(signature){
    if(signature.value == ""){
      this.signedContract = false;
      this.contractValidationMessage = "Please select signing person's name";
    }
    else{
      this.signedContract = true;
      this.contractValidationMessage = "";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Angular the standard Validators will run as you type. They will even run before you have typed anything, so often the form is full of errors before you even typed anything. Often you don't need to work with blur like you do :

```
(blur) = 'validateContractSignature(contractSignedBy)'
```

In you case it looks like you only testing a required. Angular has a standard validator for this.

```
<select required></select>
```

Look at: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/10/angular-7-template-driven-forms-validation-example

If you want more control of the form you should checkout ReactiveForms instead of Templet driven forms

Comment: Thanks for the insight @jens, I'll try to implement the same, upvoting :)